# How can I adjust the zoom control to show all points?

Tags: android, overlay, zooming, android-mapview

Sorry if this has already been asked here, but I haven't found any similar issue. My question is a short one, but also a tricky one: in Android's Google MapView, how can I adjust the zoom control to show a set of overlay points within a mapview? in technical words, I'd like to code the following algorithm:

```
List<GeoPoint> L = getPoints()
mapZoomLevel = 1
while (not(all points in L are visible in map)) {
    mapZoomLevel++
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an `ItemizedOverlay`, you could do this:

```
public void zoomOverlays() {
    mMapView.getController().zoomToSpan(itemizedOverlay.getLatSpanE6(), itemizedOverlay.getLonSpanE6());
}
```

In other words, you should really use `ItemizedOverlay` if you weren't.

Comment: Hi tolgap. Thanks for the reply. Yes, I'm using OverlayItem. Your solution works fine, but I'd like to draw the highest possible zoom to view all points. I've just tested this snippet here, and it drawed a zoom that contains all points but were too low level (too much zoom out).

Comment: Hmm, it shouldn't do that. That method should zoom to the bounding box of all items, and not the entire map. I'm at a loss then.